# Problem using MySQL query using WHERE IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On my website I am trying to program a feature where a user can choose to get 'updates' from another user. When a user clicks 'receive updates,' it throws that users ID in the database, alongside with other users they want to receive updates from. For Example (4,5,6,7,8). My tables look like this

```
members | updates
-----------------
     id | id
updates | member_id 
        | content
        | content_date
```

When I query the database I want to pull out of the updates table only the updates from the already specified users in members:updates.

```
$sql_updates = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                              FROM updates a, 
                                   members b 
                             WHERE a.member_id IN b.updates 
                          ORDER BY a.content_date DESC 
                             LIMIT 10");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_updates)) {
```

Is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: Does the `b.updates` column store the values as a comma delimited list?

Comment: @dystopia: the answer by @Kerrek SB was first and correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, spell you column names correctly -- `mem_id` or `member_id`, what shall it be? Second, this is just a plain inner join:

```
SELECT members.id AS mem_id, updates, content, content_date
FROM members JOIN updates ON(members.id = updates.member_id)
ORDER BY content_date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: didn't mean to have mem_id in there, typed it up in a hurry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in Mysql "IN" is like "OR" of programming operator if you are suing IN you need to provide an array of b.updates not just the column updates or use subquery to return array

```
$sql_updates = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM updates a, members b 
WHERE a.mem_id IN (SELECT updates from members)
ORDER BY a.content_date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Other or better way could be using JOIN

```
$sql_updates = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM updates a JOIN members b ON (a.mem_id = b.updates) 
ORDER BY a.content_date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a third table "subscriptions" which would link "members" and "updates" tables.

Sample table structure:

```
subscriptions  
-------------  
id  
member_id  
update_id
```

For each subscription (click on "receive updates"), you would create a row in "subscriptions" table.

Answer (score 0):

A join can give you extra results in cases where an in would make sense. Usually I recommend the exists operator because it performs the same as a join but gives the behavior of an in.  You can save yourself using a distinct later on.

```
$sql_updates = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                              FROM updates a
                      where exists (select * from members b                              
                        WHERE a.member_id  b.updates)
                          ORDER BY a.content_date DESC 
                             LIMIT 10");
```